Svelte - getting ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND from svelte.config.js
I am learning Svelte currently and I am not sure what is causing this error. The error exists within every one of my .svelte files, though it is not actually preventing the app from running.
I am using VSCode and at the top of each of my .svelte files, if I hover over <script lang="ts">, it shows the following error:
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '@sveltejs/adapter-static' imported from svelte.config.js

In my svelte.config.js I have this import:
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';
And in my package.json I have "@sveltejs/adapter-static": "3.0.1" under devDependencies
I have tried restarting VSCode, rerunning pnpm install and a handful of other suggestions I found while searching this error, but so far I haven't had any luck getting the error to go away.
Any ideas?

Try deleting the node_modules folder, and possibly also the package-lock.json file, and then try to run your install command again. If I remember right, the error means that the @sveltejs/adapter-static doesn't appear in the node_modules folder, and the only way to get it there is by using the install command, if I remember right. Why it isn't there/you can't get it there is a mystery, though.

@PeppeL-G thanks for the tip! I deleted my pnpm-lock.json file and then re-ran pnpm install again and this time it worked. Please add as an answer if you would like. Thanks again!

No problems! If you don't mind, write your own answer and accept it ^^
